# How get the "create assembly" output text for post-build script?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

I have a SQL Trigger project.

Currently, when I go to "Project->Publish", I can choose "generate script", it will generate a script for me and include my project's assembly via a line:

```
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyProject.MyObject]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 0x4F5C8000....
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
GO
ALTER ASSEMBLY [MyProject.MyObject]
    DROP FILE ALL
    ADD FILE FROM 0x4D5743....
```

I want to generate that on `build` and grab that as text (for Powershell) so i can put it in another file.

I know how to put it in another file via powershell, but how do I generate it on post-build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I needed two steps in my build script:

```
#Step 1: Get the file as bytes
$fileBytes = Get-Content -Path $myFilePath -Encoding Byte

#Step 2: Convert it to Hex using a BitConverter
#Step 2a: Remove the dashes it puts in each byte's hex
$fileInHex = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($fileBytes) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "-", "" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add you call .ps1 file into .csproj file, write block  `<propertyGroup>` if not exist. It seems like this:

`<Target>
...
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\postbuild.ps1"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>`